Did my contractor waterproof my windows properly?
I have a contractor enclosing a screened in patio with windows, OSB, house wrap, rigid foam insulation, rain screen, and hardie plank siding.
That said, my observation with his work is:

Window Sill is not flashed with bituminous tape or a tub (sill is completely unprotected).  I cannot easily check, but I would imagine the windows were set in caulking all the way around, but to my understanding, only caulking should again go everywhere but the bottom so that water can drain out.
Bottom of Window is taped to outside of house wrap, it should not be taped
House wrap at window head is not over top of window flashing, but instead taped to the frame like the others.
Metal flashing wrapping wood butts up to the foam insulation instead of the OSB.  It should butt up to the OSB and be taped to OSB with bituminous tape.
There is no metal flashing where the OSB meets the existing brick wall.  There should be metal flashing with silicone caulking at the brick junction and then either silicone caulking where it meets OSB or bituminous tape.

These are all places where water can get in and then get trapped where it cannot get out.
Of less significance is that I specifically asked for Dupont Tyvek as it is more breathable than Lowes House Wrap.
Am I misunderstanding?  My contractor has a license and seems to know his stuff, but this does not look right to me.  I appreciate a second opinion as this is something that I will live with for a while and want to get it right.



You'd be better off checking with your local inspector. Their opinions would carry a lot more weight to the contractor than a bunch of internet people.

Agreed, but I thought this site facilitated those discussions.  If I'm totally out of touch then I wouldn't bother the local building inspector.

Some pictures would really help us visualize your situation rather than just trying to interpret what you're trying to explain just with words.

If the contract specifies a particular brand name (DuPont Tyvek) vs "housewrap", then you've got something to discuss. However, AFAIK, all the "house brand" house wraps are made from DuPont Tyvek, then just printed with a different label ("Lowe's", "Home Depot", "Menards", "Bob's Lumber", whatever) than the stuff that says "DuPont". (I may be wrong, but this is my understanding.)

Have you looked at the mfr's instructions?  Failure to follow those would seem to be prima facie evidence of improper installation, regardless of brand.

Yes, in this case Jeld Wen has steps 3 and 6 outlining what I said along with ASTM E2112, those match everything I've stated above.  Failure to follow those instructions means the warranty would be voided.

That may be, but the "specs" listed on both Lowes and Home Depot show a much lower perm rating than the name brand stuff.  I agree that if it is covered with rigid foam, it cannot breathe as if the rain screen were directly on top of that, but still, I requested that.

@john Doe, it sounds like you have already decided it is not correct, so have at it with your builder.  It appears that no matter what is stated here, your satisfaction will only be earned by complete compliance with your decided specifications.

I discussed with my builder and he agreed to all my points and will remediate the work.  I  discussed with him earlier and thought we were all good, but am frustrated a bit that it didn't turn out that way.  I need to keep a closer eye, but don't want to watch every nail get driven in.
